# Confusion in convert time to mktime

Tags: php

I am using `strtotime` function to convert date to timestamp like

```
    echo strtotime('4-5-2013');
```

its give result 1367618400. which is right. my problem is what if , if the date is in format mm-dd-yyyy instead of dd-mm-yyyy. for example same date is in 5-april instead of 4-may.

Comment: Many a times, this could be a wonky date format that could be interpreted differently by different readers. You should be using a textual month instead.

Comment: is there is any rules of thumb or any function where i send format of date and date and get correct mktime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your latest comment

you can use

```
echo date("M-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 1997));
```

to pass any format and use mktime function.

Comment: ok i make this solution 'strtotime(date("d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 1997)));'

Answer (score 4):

strtotime treats strings with `-` in them as `dd-mm-yyyy` and `/` as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

`4-5-2013` will be 4-may

`4/5/2013` will be 5 apr

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo strtotime('5-4-2013');//Oupt puts 1367650800

echo strtotime('4-5-2013');//Oupt puts 1367618400
```